# addToBackStack can't load previous fragment data (back to

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have some problem with `Fragment` and `addToBackStack`. I am create some project using `Activity`, `Fragment`, `ActionBar`, navigation spinner. Activity (MainActivity) is parent with two fragment (BestFragment and CurrFragment). BestFragment using action bar with navigation spinner to call two data (Buy and Sell) and display in `Listview` (default load is Buy data). When listview (BestFragment) setonitemclicklistener then calling detail selected item and display to CurrFragment. I am using addToBackStack from BestFragment to CurrFragment. When i am choose Sell data from navigation spinner (BestFragment) and selected item in `Listview`, it will be send detail on CurrFragment. If i am press back button in action bar (CurrFragment), that's can be back to BestFragment but that's load default Buy data (not Sell data on previous BestFragment). Help me.

Main Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;

    case android.R.id.home:
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        //setTitle(navMenuTitles[1]);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

BestFragment

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int p,
                long arg3) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //ambil mata uang
            String des = bestList.get(p).getMataUang();

            //ambil kata terakhir textview
            String a[] = textinfobest.getText().toString().split(" ");
            String last_text = a[a.length-1];


            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            CurrFragment llf = new CurrFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("tambah title", des +" "+last_text);
            bundle.putString("pilih",des+last_text);
            llf.setArguments(bundle);
            ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, llf);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();



        }
        });
```